# How do I remove a common prefix from multiple labels in SAS?

Tags: sas

So i have hundreds of variables, some of which are labeled with the common prefix "P0 - ". Instead of removing this prefix from each of the labels manually I've tried various SQL and macro functions without any luck (i'm a rookie when it comes to SQL). Any help in producing the correct syntax would be highly appreciated!

Failed syntax:

```
proc sql noprint;
  select catx(' ', label,'=',tranwrd(label,'P0 - ',''))
    into :rcode separated by ' ' 
  from dictionary.columns 
  where libname='WORK' and memname='DSET'
; 
quit ; 
%put &rcode ; 

proc datasets library=work ;
  modify dset ;
  attrib _all_ label= &rcode; 
run;
```

Comment: Can you provide us the SQL with which you tried to get the result you want?

Comment: Added the failed code

Comment: How do you change labels using SQL? Doesn't SQL use only the column names and not the labels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're along the right lines, but there are a few errors in your code.  Firstly, you need to assign the label to the column, rather than rename the label.  In `dictionary.columns` this is the `name` variable (i.e. the macro should store `name = new_label` rather than `label = new_label`).

Secondly, you don't need the keywords `attrib` and `all` in `proc datasets`.  `attrib` is used in a data step to assign attributes and `all` is used where you want to apply the same label to all variables, most typically setting them all to missing.  The correct syntax (once you've put in the `modify` statement) is `label column1 = label1 column2 = label2` etc.

Try the following code, which should work, although I haven't fully tested it.  I've added another statement to the `where` clause in the first step to only include columns where the label begins with 'PO - ', as it looks like you don't want to change any others.

```
proc sql noprint; 
select 
    catx(' ', name,'=',tranwrd(label,'P0 - ','')) 
into: 
    rcode separated by ' ' 
from 
    dictionary.columns 
where 
    libname='WORK' 
    and 
    memname='DSET'
    and
    label eqt 'P0 - '; 
quit ; 

%put &rcode ; 

proc datasets library=work ; 
modify dset ;
    label &rcode; 
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code and it works on mock-up data. Label value should be encapsulated in parenthesis. And I used column_name = "new label" in proc datasets.

```
data DSET;
    length A B C 3;
    label 
        A = 'P0 - A'
        B = 'P0 - B'
        C = 'P0 - C'
    ;
run;

proc sql noprint;
    select cat(strip(name), '=', '"', strip(tranwrd(label, 'P0 - ','')), '"') 
        into: rcode separated by ' ' 
    from dictionary.columns where libname='WORK' and memname='DSET';
quit;

%put &rcode;

proc datasets library=work;
    modify dset;
    label
        &rcode
    ;
run;
```